# How to detect click on canvas shape?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

My goal is having a "widget" (it doesn't necessarily have to be a `Widget()`) with a non-rectangular shape, that still allows me to register hooks to detect if the user has clicked on it. Since it is not directly possible (as far as I know) to make the widget a different shape, I thought I'd just draw a shape o a canvas, and try to detect a mouseclick on that particular shape. (But maybe I'm going in a completely wrong direction, please tell me if you can suggest better way!)

So here is an MCVE that draws some irregular shape using `Mesh()`. Is it now somehow possible to attach a hook to this `Mesh()`?

To add some more context: In the end I will need many of these irregularly shaped objects that may even overlap. Think of a simple puzzle game.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Mesh, Color

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            Mesh(vertices=[100, 100, 0, 0,
                           100, 200, 0, 0,
                           130, 130, 0, 0,
                           190, 110, 0, 0
                           ],
                 indices=range(4),
                 mode='triangle_fan')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write some code to detect if the touch point collides with your shape. There are probably libraries for this, but the basic algorithms for checking if a point (i.e. the `touch.pos`) collides with a polygon (i.e. the arbitrarily-shaped mesh) are fairly straightforward to implement.

> Is it now somehow possible to attach a hook to this Mesh()?

Kivy doesn't provide anything special for this, but nor does it need to: you know what shape you want to test collision with since you defined that shape when creating the Mesh, so you can straightforwardly use the same information to do the collision calculation on the same shape.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hoped I could avoid implementing that myself, but it seems I have to give it a go:)